# ¿Qué tipo de pregunta se acepta? (¿Por qué mi pregunta está en espera?)

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas

Quiero aprender qué tipo de preguntas son buenas en esta comunidad. Mi duda es en general, pero usaré un ejemplo particular. El ejemplo es una pregunta [sobre Maven](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1106/c%C3%B3mo-agregar-los-jar-de-las-bibliotecas-librer%C3%ADas-al-class-path-del-manifest).

En demasiadas ocasiones tuve dicha duda, y volvía a buscar y encontrar las mismas respuestas en SO en inglés, y las mismas páginas en los manuales de Maven.

Por tanto, supongo que otros programadores se han enfrentado, y enfrentarán, a la misma pregunta. Por tanto, la agregué y la contesté en el mismo paso.

El centro de ayuda dice que es tema de esta comunidad: "herramientas de software comúnmente utilizadas por programadores".

Sinceramente, no sé qué me faltó. Tal vez mi duda es muy sencilla una vez que ya se sabe la respuesta, pero sí es muy engorroso buscarla una y otra vez en el Web. Tal vez fue poco clara o incompleta.

Ojalá quien votó porque se pusiera en espera me pudiera orientar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acá hay una [guía](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error) (pendiente de traducción por cierto) de cosas que una pregunta debe tener para cumplir con los estándares mínimos de calidad del sitio. Algunas cosas que creo no se cumplieron fueron:

> A reasonable explanation of what your question is. Add as much detail as you can.

Traducido:

> Una explicación razonable de qué trata tu pregunta con tantos detalles como sea posible.

Respecto a tu pregunta no veo que hayas añadido detalles significativos, ni qué error o en qué me afecta que `maven` haya omitido tal cosa. Simplemente es una oración parecida a esta:

`Maven no hizo tal cosa, ¿cómo la hago? (y pones la respuesta abajo)`

Me encantaría ver en qué me afecta o de qué trata la pregunta un poco más a detalle para que sea más clara a la comunidad.

Otra cosa es esta:

> Any background research you've tried but wasn't enough to solve your problem.

Traducido:

> Cualquier investigación o intento que hayas hecho para tratar de resolver el problema pero no que no haya sido suficiente.

Simplemente no veo eso en la pregunta. Si esto no aplica para mi pregunta debería preguntarme ¿es esto algo que puedo resolver con una simple búsqueda en Google? Y en caso de aplicar entonces sería bueno ponerlo.

Como recomendación general te recomendaría preguntarte lo siguiente:

> ¿Es tu pregunta suficientemente detallada y explicada para entenderse del todo sin ver la respuesta? ¿Podrían otros responderla o tendrían que preguntarte antes de qué estás hablando?

Todo esto te lo digo de manera constructiva, no lo tomes a mal. Si quieres editar tu pregunta y mejorarla yo seré el primero en votar para una reapertura.

Saludos

Comment: Claro que no lo tomo a mal. :-) Trataré de mejorar en el futuro. Gracias.