# Deshabilitar cierre de preguntas recientes

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas, votos-de-cierre

No sé si esta sugerencia se podría implementar en este sitio en concreto pero, ¿es posible y/o recomendable deshabilitar la opción de "cerrar" para preguntas que tengan menos de X tiempo?

Muchas veces las preguntas acaban en las colas de revisión y/o cerradas demasiado rápido, sin dar opción al autor a actualizar la pregunta o incluso reaccionar a los comentarios de "*traduce la pregunta al español*" o "*añade código*".

Sé que el autor puede editar incluso después de que la pregunta se ponga en espera, pero el hecho de que acabe en espera en cuestión de minutos puede desmotivar la participación. Y no sólo de la persona que pregunta, si no de usuarios que, una vez corregida la pregunta, quieren responder pero no pueden porque la reapertura parece bastante más lenta.

Comment: Sería bueno saber qué dicen al respecto las [estadísticas de clausura](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats), pues nos daría una idea objetiva sobre la repercusión real que tiene cerrar una pregunta y si las ediciones de quien pregunta acaban fructificando en que la pregunta se reabra. Desgraciadamente no tengo acceso a ellas (<10K).

Comment: He hecho una [captura de esa página](http://i.imgur.com/KHnjzY7.png). Pero creo que esa estadística puede llevar a equívocos o malas interpretaciones. Puede que al cerrarse la pregunta, el usuario ni se plantee editarla, sino crear una nueva o no crear nada.

Comment: ¿Es normal que una de cada cuatro preguntas acabe cerrada? Parece un porcentaje demasiado alto.

Comment: Mucho me parece. En [so] está en el 10%

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo en que, aunque el usuario tiene la posibilidad de editar y solicitar reabrir la pregunta, la mayoría de las veces tienen un impacto negativo en como los usuarios nuevos perciben el trato que les damos los usuarios en este sitio.

Comment: Por cierto, cuando dije "mucho me parece" no sé si me expliqué. ¡Me refiero a que el número es altísimo! "No está claro lo que se pregunta" y "Demasiado amplia" se comen 2/3 del total, luego parece que deberíamos atacar ese punto. Y lo que entiendo de ese punto es que la gente no pregunta bien, luego hay que mejorar la ayuda a la hora de redactar, documentación, etc. Corremos el riesgo de ser una web para hacer los deberes a la gente, así que no veo mal cerrar si la gente no pone esfuerzo.

Answer (score 5):

No se en otros tags, pero en los que yo sigo (.Net) es mas bien al revés. Preguntas que deberían cerrarse inmediatamente tardan horas en cerrarse,dias, o directamente no se cierran.

Detecto últimamente una preocupación por el tema del cierre de preguntas que yo al menos no comparto. Lo primero es un matiz que para mi es importante: las preguntas no se cierran, se **ponen en espera**. El significado de esto parece que no está claro para mucha gente. La pregunta queda a la espera de que una posible edición la vuelva a hacer apta para el sitio. Si la pregunta se edita,entra en la cola de reapertura y si efectivamente los motivos de su cierre ya no existen, probablemente sea reabierta.

Por otro lado,que una pregunta se cierre no es decisión de una persona,a no ser que este sea un moderador. Esto es un tema diferente (que en parte ha sido tratado por ejemplo en [¿Se puede decidir en Meta?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2242/se-puede-decidir-en-meta)) y que yo opino que solo debe hacerse en casos extraordinarios. Pero obviando esa excepción, tiene que haber 5 usuarios que estén de acuerdo para que una pregunta se ponga en espera.

El sistema de Stack Exchange lleva mucho tiempo en funcionamiento y se basa en la automoderación de los usuarios. Esto tiene cosas buenas y malas, y por supuesto debemos ser criticos y tratar de mejorar en todo lo posible. Pero cuando una pregunta se pone en espera, es decisión de varias personas que, bajo su criterio (tan válido como el de que no está de acuerdo) piensan que una pregunta no tiene cabida **en su estado actual** en el sitio.

P.D. En mi caso personal, yo trato de poner un comentario para que la pregunta pueda ser mejorada, y si transcurrido un tiempo no ha sido así, en ese momento procedo a votar su cierre. Pero esto no tiene por que ser la norma.

Answer (score 1):

Comparto tu preocupación sobre el efecto que tiene el "cierre relámpago" de preguntas de "usuarios no ávidos", sin embargo, aún no estoy seguro de la conveniencia de hacer excepciones.

Por otro lado, me parece que requerimos más participación a través de los votos. Véase [Vota pronto, vota con frecuencia](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2209/65)

Me parece que valdría la pena revisitar otros hilos sobre la temática de cierre

- [¿Qué tipo de pregunta se acepta? (¿Por qué mi pregunta está en espera?)](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277/65)
- [¿Qué criterio siguen ustedes al manejar las colas de revisión para votos de cierre y reapertura?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1253/65)
- [¿Somos demasiados exigentes con las preguntas de los usuarios?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1466/65)

Answer (score 0):

Recientemente obtuve el privilegio para acceder a las colas de revisión de cierre y reapertura en SOes. Aunque ya me lo había preguntado antes, recién externalicé

[¿Es posible posponer la revisión de cierre o reapertura?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2258/65)

A lo que voy es que los revisores tenemos la posibilidad de dar una *tregua temporal* a las usuarios nuevos y para ello no hace falta cambiar nada en el sistema. En realidad esto no hace las cosas ni más fáciles ni más homogéneas ni más coherentes porque depende de la postura de cada revisor y por ello reitero la invitación a que **como comunidad usemos más Meta** tal como en este caso lo está haciendo Alvaro (el OP).