# ¿Debemos estar mas atentos a la cola de reapertura?

Tags: discusión, votos-de-reapertura

A raiz de cierta polémica que se está creando ultimamente sobre los cierres de preguntas, yo ya expresé mi opinión en [Deshabilitar cierre de preguntas recientes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2243/15301) ,que por hacer un pequeño resumen es que los cierres no son tales, si no que son puestas en espera.

Pero surge un problema que para mi si es importante, y es que debemos ser ágiles en la reapertura de preguntas una vez hayan sido editadas y encajen en el sitio. En el momento de escribir esto hay dos ejemplos claros:

- [Obtener permisos totales para mover archivos a la tarjeta externa: microSD](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/81837/15301)
- [¿Cómo incluir un certificado en MSXML6 usando VBA?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/79820/15301)

En uno de los casos la pregunta se cerró por estar en ingles, y en el otro por ser muy pobre en su primera edición. En ambos casos para mi estaban correctamente puestas en espera.

Pero con posterioridad las dos preguntas se editaron y los problemas que llevaron a su cierre fueron solucionados. Lamentablemente, es muy probable que tarden en ser reabiertas o incluso que nunca lo sean.

De ahi mi pregunta. No es la cola de reapertura una de las mas importantes? Si reaccionamos rápido a ella, no daremos la impresión a los nuevos usuarios de que, si hacen las cosas bien obtendrán mas facilmente la ayuda que necesitan?

Comment: Bien visto. Para el caso de la pregunta en inglés, pregunté [¿Podríamos tener un pequeño detector de publicaciones en inglés que notificara a los autores?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2043/83). Ahorraría tiempo a mucha gente (revisores, autor...).

Comment: @fedorqui me parece una propuesta interesantisima. No la habia visto, pero estoy totalmente a favor.

Comment: No iría al extremo de llamarla "una de las más importantes", pero sin duda debería estar siempre en 0 para cada usuario. Esto no era un problema antes de la graduación (al menos yo no lo consideraba). Quizás, hasta que crezca el número de usuarios con reputación para revisar, podemos usar el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) para darle visibilidad a las que deberían reabrirse más rápido. Invito a que los que detecten estos casos (tengan o no reputación para reabrir) publiquen el enlace a la pregunta en el chat.

Comment: Cuando digo _una de las más importantes_ me refiero a la percepcion que un nuevo usuario puede tener cuando una pregunta se le pone en espera, se esfuerza en adecuarla y aun así permanece cerrada. Otras colas son mas importantes respecto a la calidad del sitio, pero en cuanto a la relación con nuevos usuarios si me parece de las mas importantes. Lo del chat me parece una buena idea

Comment: La primer pregunta ya ha sido reabierta. La segunda no puedo ver si tiene o no votos de reapertura.

Comment: La segunda está con 4 votos @Rubén :)

Comment: Pues va bastante rápido ¿no?

Comment: Bueno, la edición que para mi califica para reabrir es de hace 2 horas. A mi me gustaría que fuera mas rapido, ademas estas dos preguntas hay que tener en cuenta que han tenido mas atencion por ponerlas aqui y haberse comentado en el chat, sino habria que ver cuanto habrian tardado

Comment: 2 horas **no** me parece mucho sobre todo considerando que la revisión es realizada por unos pocos voluntarios sin compromiso de horario, volumen de revisión, etc., etc. Por cierto, recién tuve acceso a la revisión de reapertura. En este momento tengo 0 por revisar.

Comment: Estoy siendo más activo en las colas de revisión desde hace un tiempo, pero un problema que me encuentro es que uso mucho la app móvil de Stack Exchange, y no las incluye, lo cual limita un poco.

Comment: Si,la aplicación de Stack Exchange deja muchisimo que desear. Y la de Stack Overflow yo diría que es peor aun,una pena...

Comment: Si bien no es lo más cómodo, yo reviso desde el celular más seguido que desde otro lado... Ojalá hubiese una aplicación, pero no encuentro casi ningún problema (salvo los +1 en comentarios de algunas colas).

Comment: La verdad deje un poco olvidadas las colas de revisión desde en nuevo diseño de la barra, antes me aparecia un indicador, ahora ya no.

Answer (score 2):

Una  de las cosas a tener presente es que el acceso a las colas de revisión está sujeta a privilegios.

Hoy hay alrededor de 45 usuarios con una reputación de `3 000+` que son los requeridos con [emitir votos para cerrar y reabrir](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions). De esos alrededor de 45 me parece que todavía son muchos menos los que participan en el proceso de revisión.

> NOTA: A raíz de la graduación del sitio, la reputación requerida para contar con ciertos privilegios se incrementó.

Comment: Estoy totalmente de acuerdo @Rubén y precisamente hace poco lo comenté. Se que poco a poco al aumentar el numero de revisores la cosa irá mejorando, pero quería dar un toque de atención a los que si tenemos reputación suficiente para prestar una atención especial a esa cola.

Comment: También pensé en esto. Sin embargo, en principio estas mismas personas son las que pueden cerrar. ¿Será que se dedican más esfuerzos a cerrar que a abrir? En tal caso gana enteros la hipótesis de @Pikoh de estar más atentos a la cola de reapertura para equilibrar ese flujo de votos.

Comment: Me parece muy bien el toque de atención que has hecho, de ninguna forma lo estoy demeritando. Al contrario, mi intención es contribuir a que esa atención se de a que juntos encontremoes la dirección correcta.

Comment: Creo que simplemente las preguntas en colaboración de reapertura son muy pocas. No es que dediquemos más recursos por cerrar  qué por reabrir como dice @fedorqui, simplemente hay muchísimas menos. Son tan pocas qué no creo que sea un verdadero problema.

Comment: @toledano: Me parece que situaciones en las que si un revisor ya votó por cerrar/reabrir no lo puede volver a hacer. Supongo que cuando hay una edición ese "candado" por llamarlo de alguna forma se libera.

Comment: Lo que me parece es que da la impresión de que existe el mismo número de preguntas para cerrar que para abrir y que los revisores prefieren usar su esfuerzo en cerrar y no en reabrir, como parece decir fedorqui, pero eso es falso. El tiempo (o esfuerzo) es muchísimo menor, porque no es el mismo número. No requieren el mismo esfuerzo. Una pregunta en espera no se transforma automáticamente en una pregunta en cola de reapertura. Hay muy pocas preguntas de reapertura. Etc.

Answer (score 2):

El tuyo es un buen ejemplo de como actuar.

Has llamado la atención en meta sobre dos preguntas que merecen ser reabiertas. Y pronto se han reabierto. Esto es algo que se puede hacer en Meta tantas veces que sea necesario sobre tantas preguntas como sea necesario reabrir pero que no hayan atraido suficiente atención. Lo mismo valdría para cerrar si hiciese falta.