# ¿Es posible posponer la revisión de cierre o reapertura?

Tags: soporte, revisión-de-pregunta, colas-de-revisión

En las colas de revisión de cierre o reapertura se muestra el número de preguntas a revisar. Al acceder a una de ellas se muestra una pregunta a la vez y varias opciones.

En algunas discusiones se ha hablado que en el caso de publicaciones de nuevos usuarios podría ser "traumático" el que su primeras publicaciones sean "cerradas" a los pocos minutos u horas de haber sido publicadas.

Según entiendo, si doy clic al botón "omitir" ya no podré ver esa pregunta en la cola de revisión. ¿Hay alguna forma de posponer la revisión de una pregunta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sí, es posible volver a revisar preguntas que omitiste:

Primero pulsa en *revisiones recientes* de la cola que quieres revisar:

[image]

Después, pincha en la ventana *Historial*:

[image]

Ahora,en la parte de abajo tienes la opción *Mostrar revisiones Omitidas*:

[image]

Por último,buscas la publicación en cuestión y pulsas en *Omitir*

---

*Traducción/adaptación de [esta respuesta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307302/579895)*

Comment: Salgo en la fotooooo se me olvidó sonreír :)

Comment: es que igual es dificil hacer una captura en la que no salgas @fedorqui ;)