# ¿Es válido dar una oportunidad a un usuario novel antes de votar para cerrar?

Tags: discusión, usuarios-nuevos, votos-de-cierre

Esto me lo estoy preguntando desde que tengo el acceso a los votos de cierre. No sé si hay un criterio orgánico, pero si he leído opiniones al respecto de dar a un usuario nuevo una "oportunidad" para corregir una pregunta mal formulada, o escrita en otro lenguaje, o con errores que uno estima, con un poco de esfuerzo se podrían subsanar. En ese caso, el criterio que trato de seguir es:

Si la pregunta es de un usuario novel, y fue recientemente formulada:

- Trato de orientar con algún comentario a menos que ya le hayan hecho alguno
- Omito el voto

¿Es válido este criterio? ¿Y en el caso de dar la oportunidad, es correcto "omitir" o debiera indicar "dejar abierta"?

Comment: Si la pregunta está mal formulada, __debería usarse el voto de cierre__. Eso le da una oportunidad al usuario novel para corregirla o subsanarla. Porque en realidad no se cierran, se ponen en espera. En espera de que se corrijan. El criterio es tan válido como cualquier otro que cumpla con las reglas.

Comment: Relacionado: [¿Qué criterio siguen ustedes al manejar las colas de revisión para votos de cierre y reapertura?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1253/65)

Comment: @toledano Falso, el voto de cierre no da la oportunidad al usuario novel de corregirla o subsanarla. Esa oportunidad ya la tenía antes de que se votase a cerrar. Un voto de cierre tiene como efecto principal "No se pueden añadir respuestas". Y algún otro efecto como "borrado de la pregunta si se cumplen ciertas otras condiciones además del cierre".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sí es válido dar una oportunidad.
Pero no actues en contra de tu propio criterio. No votes para mantener abierta una pregunta que piensas que no lo merece. Eso adultera el sistema.
Sí puedes omitir el voto. Escribir un comentario explicando cómo usar el sitio suele ser bienvenido. Y si pasado un tiempo los problemas de la pregunta no se corrigen siempre estás a tiempo de votar a cerrar, se puede hacer desde la misma pregunta, no tiene por qué ser desde revisión.

Answer (score 3):

**Es válido dar oportunidad!**, cuando detectas que un usuario novel agrega su respuesta y no cumple con los requerimientos del sitio, es recomendable sugerirle cambios para que su pregunta cumpla con la calidad aceptada en el sitio.

Si embargo te refieres a la cola de revisión:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/close/56958

- La opción **"Omitir"** puede ser usada para concederle la revisión a otro usuario, por ejemplo, en el caso que no conozcas la tecnología de la que habla la pregunta o no estas seguro de la decisión.
- La opción "**Dejar abierta"** indica que estas de acuerdo que la pregunta cumple con la calidad requerida en el sitio.

---

Incluso si la pregunta es cerrada (puesta en espera), el usuario (OP) recibe la notificación y puede modificarla para que cumpla la calidad aceptada en el sitio, si esto sucede puede ser reabierta, esto es muy común.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

## Respuesta corta

En mi opinión personal sí es válido.

## Explicación

Muchos de los usuarios nuevos no han escuchado sobre Stack Exchange y han llegado aquí por algún enlace "de allá afuera". Ya sea por haberlo sufrido en carne propia o a través de otros, varios miembros de la comunidad pensamos que el que la pregunta sea puesta en espera muy pronto sin haber recibido ningún comentario es desconcertante. El recorrido no explica esta parte, los mensajes de predefinidos no son claros para muchos usuarios nuevos y el centro de ayuda es muy complicado en particular cuando a uno le apremia recibir ayuda.

Mi criterio es más o menos como lo que sigue:

Si la pregunta

- es de un usuario nuevo
- es reciente (menos de 6-24 horas)
- está dentro de la temática del sitio
- es "rescatable"

Entonces

- dejar un comentario
- hacer clic en Omitir

Ocasionalmente reviso "mis omitidos" para ver que ha pasado con ellos.

Relacionado

- [¿Es posible posponer la revisión de cierre o reapertura?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2258/65)